# Accessing a CalendarView in a fragment via Java

Tags: java, android

I want to use a CalendarView in a Fragment but I can't find out how to access it via Java. For the start I just wanted to display the selected date in a toast but the function doesn't seem to be called if I click on a date.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SchedulerFragment">
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/scheduler_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></CalendarView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class SchedulerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CalendarView calendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.scheduler_calendar);

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Toast.makeText(SchedulerActivity.this, "Date changed to" + i2 + "." + i1 + "." + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: **1** - you are using an Activity to show the calendar, not a fragment. **2** - you have not called `setContentView`. Do you get any errors in the logcat?

Comment: I tried using the `SchedulerFragment` class but there I can't call `Toast.makeText()` because I don't know which context I should enter there. I'm now calling `setContentView` but the app never stops if I add a breakpoint at  `Toast.maketext`. There are also no errors in logcat.

Comment: please add the code with the Fragment

Comment: Sorry for the late response
https://github.com/dundunn/Example

Comment: I checked your code, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `setOnDateChangeListener` in the `onViewCreated` method and use `getActivity()` in your Toast. I tested the below code and it was working.

```java
public class SchedulerFragment extends Fragment {

    private CalendarView calendarView;

    public SchedulerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.scheduler_calendar);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull final CalendarView view, final int year, final int month,
                    final int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date changed to" + dayOfMonth + "." + month + "." + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduler, container, false);
        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are working solution for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/scheduler_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity as below

```
public class SchedulerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CalendarView calendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.scheduler_calendar);

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Toast.makeText(SchedulerActivity.this, "Date changed to" + i2 + "." + i1 + "." + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the toast is still not being triggered when I'm pressing on a date.

Comment: @dun : Let me check

Comment: @dun : It is working for me, By selecting any dated it is showing toast message "Date changed to day.month.year"

Comment: It will work if it's an activity but in my case it's a fragment that's being displayed by a ViewPager.